# Selenium Python Execute Script in JavaScript Console not working

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Good morning. I'm working on a program that uses Selenium and hooks into [PokeClicker](https://pokeclicker.com). One of the primary functions it has is to automatically download saves for me. After loading a profile and being on the main page, there is a JavaScript `Class` called ​`Save` that has a function called `download()`

I can call this function in the console through the browser just fine, and it downloads the save.

I get Selenium set up, hook into the website, and that works fine, but, when I try to call the Function through

`driver.execute_script('Save.download()')`

it ends up giving me this error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: ReferenceError: Save is not defined`

Is this because Selenium is trying to load an undefined Variable instead of the `Save` Class? If so, is there a way to call a `Function` inside of a `Class` in Selenium?

I know this is probably a pretty niche problem considering the website, but I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

You have to navigate to the page where 'Start Menu' is available in the top right corner of the page, then you have to run the JS code:

```
# clicking on the 'New Save' button to navigate to the next page where 'Start Menu' available
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'New Save')]").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("Save.download()")
```

(OR)

```
# clicking on the 'Trainer' button to navigate to the next page where 'Start Menu' available
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".trainer-card .card-body").click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.execute_script("Save.download()")
```

Next time, post your question clearly.

Comment: Yeah, I worded it bad, because this is not the solution I am looking for. I will reword it.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to download a save INSIDE of the game. My wording made it seem like I'm trying to download a save on the front page of the game. When I try to download a save in the game with this script, it gives me the error I described above.

Comment: To add on, you would have to start a game in order to see what I am talking about.